# How to add css or make a design on live broadcast content rtmp?

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I use the live streaming broadcast rtmp function.

I want to add css to make my live streaming  broadcast in rtmp on youtube prettier. According to the documentation, the css properties are limited. I tried to see the properties "border and background-color" but I had an error response, so it blocks well.
Is there another way for me to improve the graphical aspect of my content on youtube?

To summarize how can I add graphic elements to my live content rtmp youtube.

[EDIT]

1. The request body and CSS I Tried :

   broadcast {
             position: relative;
             padding:0;
             margin:0;
             width: 1280px;
             height:720px;
             overflow: hidden;
           }

   ```
       stream:first-child{
        display : inline-block;
        width: 49%;
        height: 99%;
        z-index: 2;
       }

       stream:first-child + .stream {
        position : absolute;
        z-index:1;
        width : 20%;
        height : 40%;
        top : 30%;
        left : 40%;
       }

      stream:last-child{
        display : inline-block;
        width: 49%;
        height: 99%;
        z-index:2;
       }
   ```
2. The error OpenTok is giving 
   error 400 Stylesheet has unsupported features
3. What is the layout you want to show

In finally a layout with 3 block, 2 in horizontal and one more small in center and in first plan.

4. What do you mean with add graphic elements
   I want the opportunity to decorate my content. Example of graphic element: borders, background color, logo addition, image, graphic text etc...

An example to illustrate : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSaQ7_1-Oug

Comment: OpenTok staff here.

Could you please provide more information on what and how are you trying to do?

1-The request body and CSS. 2-The error OpenTok is giving. 3-What is the layout you want to show. 4-What do you mean with add graphic elements

Comment: Yes I edit my post to answer you

Comment: That CSS works. I cannot help with the graphic elements, but I'm not sure you can do that.

Comment: Ok there are another way to make graphic?

Comment: @FranciscoJavierCanoSandoval Can we add background image in opentok Live streaming broadcasts? If yes, then do we need to customize css??